# Informatica Cloud: Trying to create a Connection with SQL Server

Tags: cloud, informatica, secure-gateway, iics

I am trying to create a connection for SQL Server in Informatica Cloud to connect to a local database on my computer. Therefore I am doing the following settings:

```
Type: SQL Server
Runtime Environment: The one i created
Authentication Mode: Windows Authentication (Deprecated)
Host: Laptopname\SQLEXPRESS
Port: 1433
Database Name: AdventureWorks2012
Schema: sys
Code Page: UTF-8
```

Unfortunately, I am receiving an error and I don’t figure it out, which settings I need to change. It is the following error:

***The connection test failed because of the following error: Error establishing socket to host and port, Reason: Connection refused***

Of course i have googled the error and found a few sites, who showed how to solve this issue.

The one is the following:

https://knowledge.informatica.com/s/article/495917?language=en_US

I have already checked this and edited the SQL Server Configuration Manager
to enable the TCP/IP

Unfortunatly this didnt work and the error appeares still.

Then i tried the solution from the next side:

https://knowledge.informatica.com/s/article/314982?language=en_US

For this solution i went to the Firewall and added in Inbound and Outbound the Port "1433".

I am not sure, if i did it right on this one, but it also didnt work and the error still appears.

Then i found this site, where they talk about giving access to remote connections to sql server:

https://community.adobe.com/t5/coldfusion-discussions/error-establishing-socket-to-host-reason-connection-refused-connect/td-p/2066238

here i have found the following code, which i ran in the sql server local database:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'remote access', 1;
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO
```

This is also not working for the connection.

I went also to the Computer-Manager --> Local User and Groups --> Admins and added everything, which was in the Folder named like my Computer, which is also the name of my Secure Agent. With this step i wanted to make sure, that the secure agent is part of the admin Group on my pc. I am not sure, if this was done right by me.

However this step also did not work and the error still appears.

Now i am really lost at this topic and i dont know how to solve it.

Comment: A question of the form: "I am trying to do ABC and get an error, here is my configuration and error: <screenshot>" is not a good question. Please see [ask] and [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question) Also have a look at these pages in informatica's knowledge center: [1](https://knowledge.informatica.com/s/article/495917?language=en_US), [2](https://knowledge.informatica.com/s/article/527622?language=en_US) (Note: I am not an SME)

Comment: Please improve the question. Do not include any noise such as "Thank you very much!" or "UPDATE". Please provide the error you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a Connection in IICS, you need to define a Runtime Environment (i.e Secure Agent or Group). That connection would then be established via this Secure Agent (Training, in your case). You need to ensure that this Secure Agent has access to tour target database, including firewalls etc.

Comment: This is correct. Make sure the "Training" Runtime Env selected indicates the Secure Agent created on your local machine.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answers. Can you please tell me, how i can give the access to the secure agent? I have just checked and i dont find any way to do that. I also dont find any information about that anywhere. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Maciejg, do you have an answer here maybe? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @marianonr, can you please tell me, how i can give the Secure Agent the access to the target database? I did not find any information about that neither in the IICS Documentation nor in google.

Comment: @SiverR did u able to fix this issue?

Comment: @Adam anfortunatly Not. Maybe It is Not possible due to the fact that It was a Test Version oh IIC.